# Android studio doesnt generate mipmaps

Tags: java, android

I dont know why but my android studio doesn't create mipmaps in a new project. Maybe i have to change settings to solve this problem.

Thanks for any help

Only this 
[image]

Comment: `Only this...`. In facts, `mipmaps` is intended for the application icon only. Not for the graphical resources.

Comment: change the project view from project explorer

Answer (score 0):

Android studio doesn't show me that folders but i have found it with explorer 
[image]

[image]

Comment: follow this : Right Click in mipmap under res>New>Image Asset>Give Unique name>select Clip art then next and finish. it will aotomatically save all size drawable in particular size.